# Fluctuation of thermal state of light derivation

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, thermal-radiation, quantum-optics

I am having trouble following how the expression for the variance of the photon number $$\Delta n = \langle n \rangle^2 + \langle n \rangle $$ is obtained for a thermal state of light (steps below from page 15 of Loudon's Quantum Theory of Light, 3rd Ed.): [image]

I understand that $$\Delta n = \langle n^2 \rangle + \langle n \rangle^2 $$ but I don't follow how the expression for the second factorial moment is then used to arrive at the final expression for the variance.

Comment: Use MathJax instead of images or screenshots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that $$\langle n(n-1)\rangle = \langle n^2\rangle -\langle n \rangle = 2\langle n \rangle ^2$$ therefore $$(\Delta n )^2 = \langle n^2\rangle - \langle n \rangle^2 = 2\langle n \rangle^2 + \langle n \rangle  -\langle n \rangle ^2 = \langle n \rangle ^2 + \langle n \rangle $$